# Oracle SQL query to find all instances of one condition

Tags: sql, oracle

A table in an Oracle database has columns PRODUCER, CONSUMER, STATUS and DATE. The value of STATUS can be either COMPLETE or FAILED

I am looking for a query which would find all the instances of PRODUCER and CONSUMER pairs where the STATUS is always FAILED

If for example the table contains

| PRODUCER | CONSUMER | STATUS | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | XXX | COMPLETE | 01/12/2022 |
| AAA | YYY | FAILED | 01/12/2022 |
| AAA | XXX | FAILED | 02/12/2022 |
| AAA | YYY | FAILED | 02/12/2022 |

I would want the query to return PRODUCER AAA and CONSUMER YYY, because their STATUS is always FAILED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or

```
select distinct producer, consumer 
from tab t
where status = 'FAILED' and not exists(
    select 1 from tab t1 where t.producer = t1.producer and t.consumer = t1.consumer and t1.status = 'COMPLETE'
);
```

Or

```
select producer, consumer
from tab
group by producer, consumer having( count(1) = count(case when status = 'FAILED' then 1 end));
```

Etc.

Comment: for the fun: 

select producer, consumer from tab
match_recognize(
 partition by producer, consumer
 order by dat
 measures classifier() as cls
 ALL ROWS PER MATCH
 pattern( ^completed*  )
 define
  completed as status = 'COMPLETE'
)
where cls is null
;

Answer (score 0):

I think using set theory might be an easier solution to this problem -

```
SELECT PRODUCER, CONSUMER
  FROM your_table
 WHERE STATUS = 'FAILED'
 MINUS
SELECT PRODUCER, CONSUMER
  FROM your_table
 WHERE STATUS <> 'FAILED';
```